# Why is diamond harder even though its packing fraction is only about 34%?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, crystals, diamond

Why is diamond harder even though its packing fraction is only about 34% (less than that of fcc)?

Answer (score 4):

Chemistry, specifically bonding, is the underlying mediator on the mechanical property. Diamond forms directional covalent bonds. Metals form non-directional metallic bonds. We cannot slide a carbon atom in diamond (slip) without breaking a directional bond and reforming the bond at an equivalent sp$^3$ tetrahedral location in the lattice. By comparison, we can slip a metal atom along any direction while mostly preserving the metallic bond, changing only the magnitude of the bond force or bond potential energy in a continuous manner.

An sp$^3$ network also has an overall macroscopic structural stability that does not exist in metals.